# Rails/Rspec JSON array of integers being converted to array of strings when testing post call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have defined param below in my spec file:

```
let(:params) do
 {
   company: {
    name: "My company",
    company_type_ids: [1,2]
   }
 }
end
```

There's no problem when I send request with the same param by postman, but when calling post request with rspec array of int in param is converted to string, like this: `company_type_ids: ["1", "2"]`

It should be `company_type_ids: [1,2]`

How can I prevent that array in param to be converted to string?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can't. The data passed to server via http(s) will always be textual or binary(file upload). Why you need ids as integer?

Comment: @AmitPatel Because I need to handle that integer array before create or update. I have a fixed list of types, and I want to get names of those type ids from list using method "select" and "include?"

Comment: You can still use string ids to search records e.g `CompanyType.find(id: params[:company_type_ids]`. No need to convert string to integer.

Comment: Actually you can pass integer array as long as you set the header `CONTENT_TYPE` to be `application/json`.